# Error running Analytic Snapshot: Some rows failed - which rows? why only 2000 rows?

Tags: custom-report-type, analytic-snapshots

I ran an Analytic snapshot, and the answer I got was that some rows have failed.

[image]

I see:

```
2000 records were inserted...
0 records failed...
```

My data has more than 2000 records, how do I debug it?
Where is the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error you are getting is because analytic snapshots only support 2000 records max at the moment. There's an existing [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Bqz2AAC) posted to vote for removing this limitation. The error 'Some rows failed' is because you are hitting the 2000 record limit. [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008k2cIAA) is a related post which may help.